# No bean exists of type error in Kotlin-micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I have a class which creates custom-named bean (test-index), but if I try to change the name of the bean to some other name (say test-index-new), it results in following error whereas the same works if the bean name is not changed:

Code:

```
@Singleton
@Requires("data-source-config.files-to-load.bigram-corpus")
class Service(
     @Named("test-index") val biGramIndexManagerService: BigramIndexManagerService // changing it to test-index-new results in below error
)
```

**BigramIndexManagerService.kt**

```
class BigramIndexManagerService {
// business-service class
}
```

> No bean of type exists for the given qualifier: @Named('test-index-new'): Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).

I have enabled annotation processing at dependencies.gradle like below:

`annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"`

And I have bigram-corpus at the application.yml file

```
data-source-config:
     files-to-load:
          bigram-corpus:
               file-path: <file_path>
               ....
```

Please let me know if I am missing something, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a lot of information to go on. What class type is `biGramIndexManagerService`? I don't know Kotlin all that well but `@Named("test-index") val biGramIndexManagerService: <Type-placeholder>` doesn't look like it would compile. Micronaut looks for beans/classes to inject by class name, generic type or annotations (see: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#qualifiers). It could be that you left off `@Singleton` on your new class. Or if you are creating beans during compile time, they aren't discoverable, which is a build issue.

Comment: @ShingJo, I had updated the question with better picture.

Comment: I did fresh build of the application and it went fine, something to do with incremental build on intellij it seems.

Comment: If you fixed your issue can you answer your own question?

Comment: sure, I will do it

Answer (score 0):

After doing clean build, the issue has been fixed. Whoever encounters this issue, please do a delete of your build folder and run it again or do a clean build. Hope this helps!